# How to not show an image if User-Agent detects internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I have a pop up image that shows after the user has switched tabs. I do not want this to show if the user is on internet explorer as I'm using the Page Visibility API (from MDN documents).

How can I test the following code works, or does anyone know if it does as I don't have Internet explorer and I'm using Cloud9 AWS, so I'm not sure it's possible.

```
 // Do not display popUp for Internet Explorer.
const popUp = document.getElementById("circle-parent");
let ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
let isIE = /MSIE|Trident/.test(ua);

if (isIE) {
  popUp.style.display === "none";
} else {
  popUp.style.display === "block";
}
```

Here's the rest of my code to see the display in more context if needed:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    popUp.style.display = "none";
  } else if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
    popUp.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

New example to check feature detection:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  // if (!cookieExists()) {
  if (!document.visibilityState && document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    popUp.style.display = "none";
  } else if (document.visibilityState && document.visibilityState === "visible") {
    popUp.style.display = "block";
    // setCookie(cookieName);
  }
  //   }
  //  else {
  //   setCookie(uklFocusCookie)
  // }
});
```

Comment: Don't bother testing for a specific browser as the `navigator.userAgent` string is notoriously not reliable. Instead of [browser detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent), use [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) and just test to see if the API you want to use exists: `if(document.visibilityState)`.

Comment: That's interesting to know, thank you. I've edited my post, do you think it looks about right  to display: none if !document.visibilityState?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: How would I do this? I only have Chrome?

Comment: Can you not download IE? If you're on a Mac, Microsoft provides VM images for testing: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Comment: Just download IE.

Comment: And by the way `!document.visibilityState` should be `document.visibilityState`. You don't want to test for NOT true, you want to test for true. And just have one `if` test that tests for this. Then you can do what you then need to test and do in the `true` branch and the `else` branch.